# Converting .xls to .txt and viceversa

Tags: r, csv

I want to know if conversion of file format is possible in R. If i have a `.xls` file and would like to convert to a `.txt` format or viceversa. likewise is conversion of other formats possible `.xls` to `.csv` and so on.

Comment: What`s the difference between csv and txt?

Answer (score 3):

Read in the `.xls` file with whatever package you like. I use `openxlsx`, but use `xlsx` for that specific file type.

```
library(xlsx)
data <- read.xlsx2(file, sheet, ...)

write.table(data, "filename.txt", ...) 

#or

write.csv(data, "filename.csv", ...)
```

Or if you want a function, try something like:

```
library(xlsx)
xls.csv.converter <- function(File, Sheet=1) {
d <- read.xlsx2(File, Sheet)
write.csv(d, paste0(getwd(), "/", substr(File, 1, nchar(File)-4),".csv"))
}

xls.csv.converter("mydata.xls")
```

Note that the function search for the file in your working directory and the file will be written to your working directory.

Comment: Thanks , will it work for `.xls`   `error: openxlsx can not read .xls or .xlm files!`

Comment: use the `xlsx` package for that instead

Comment: i think JDK need to be installed for `.xls` to use `xlsx`

Comment: I just tried it, it worked. I edited it to add a necessary forward slash.